# physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) method called before actual contact

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

Currently, my **physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact)** method is called before actual contact of two nodes. I have used debug options to display physics shapes and everything looks in order but contact detection is not precise. This started happening when I introduced complex 3D models, it was working fine with simple shapes like spheres and boxes. Also, I have tried setting physics shape to the bounding box of a node so the shape would be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found out why it was acting weird. Problem was in the position of the coordinate system. Previously for my 3D model start of coordinate system was at the start of the model, but it should have been in the middle of the model because physics body would take the right dimensions and shape but would position its middle position always in the centre of the coordinate system so it would behave like it is in front of the model.